# error 80004005 installing vc.redis.x64

Tags: windows, windows-installer

Trying to install visual c++ redistributable 2015 but getting below error

[image]

Below are the contents of log file

```
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i001: Burn v3.7.3813.0, Windows v6.3 (Build 9600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\vc_redist.x64.exe, cmdline: ''
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20170322234405.log'
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\vc_redist.x64.exe'
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\'
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64) - 14.0.23026'
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i100: Detect begin, 10 packages
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i000: Setting version variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKey' to value '10.0.10137.0'
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i000: Setting numeric variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists' to value 1
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to true.
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to true.
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to true.
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to true.
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to true.
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to true.
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to true.
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to true.
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x86, state: Present, cached: None
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x64, state: Present, cached: Complete
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x86, state: Present, cached: None
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x64, state: Present, cached: None
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Present, cached: None
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Present, cached: None
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Present, cached: None
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Present, cached: None
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64 >= v6.0 OR (VersionNT64 = v5.2 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1)' evaluates to true.
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:05]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i200: Plan begin, 10 packages, action: Install
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64)' evaluates to true.
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64' to value 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20170322234405_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64_rollback.log'
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64' to value 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20170322234405_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64.log'
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64)' evaluates to true.
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64' to value 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20170322234405_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64_rollback.log'
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64' to value 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20170322234405_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64.log'
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x86
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x64
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x86
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x64
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x86
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x64
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x86
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x64
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x86, state: Present, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x64, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x86, state: Present, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x64, state: Present, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Present, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Present, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Present, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Present, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:08]i300: Apply begin
[1670:0EBC][2017-03-22T23:44:10]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[1670:0EBC][2017-03-22T23:44:10]i361: Created a system restore point.
[1670:0EBC][2017-03-22T23:44:10]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[1670:0EBC][2017-03-22T23:44:10]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}\.be\VC_redist.x64.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}\VC_redist.x64.exe'
[1670:0EBC][2017-03-22T23:44:10]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, version: 14.0.23026.0
[1670:0EBC][2017-03-22T23:44:10]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[1BC0:038C][2017-03-22T23:44:10]i336: Acquiring container: WixAttachedContainer, copy from: C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\VC_redist.x64.exe
[1BC0:038C][2017-03-22T23:44:10]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLastUsedSource' to value 'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\'
[1BC0:1A60][2017-03-22T23:44:10]e000: Error 0x80004005: Failed to extract all files from container.
[1BC0:038C][2017-03-22T23:44:10]e000: Error 0x80004005: Faild to begin and wait for operation.
[1BC0:038C][2017-03-22T23:44:10]e000: Error 0x80004005: Failed to extract payload: a10 from container: WixAttachedContainer
[1BC0:038C][2017-03-22T23:44:10]e312: Failed to extract payloads from container: WixAttachedContainer to working path: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}\7D8FAF5C830D013F487437C88200F1E3F959E87A, error: 0x80004005.
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:10]e000: Error 0x80004005: Failed while caching, aborting execution.
[1670:0EBC][2017-03-22T23:44:10]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
[1670:0EBC][2017-03-22T23:44:10]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}
[1670:0EBC][2017-03-22T23:44:10]i352: Removing cached bundle: {e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}\
[1670:0EBC][2017-03-22T23:44:10]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[1BC0:1BD4][2017-03-22T23:44:10]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80004005, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Please suggest me how to fix it .

Answer (score 0):

This log line

```
Error 0x80004005: Failed to extract all files from container.
```

indicates that it is a file-related error.

Unfortunately HRESULT 0x80004005 just means "[unspecified failure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704587.aspx)", so there could be many reasons, e. g. the setup.exe is damaged or there are insufficient permissions on the extraction directory.

Comment: I my case downloading setup again for three times works :( . Cant figure out what was the reason .